# When can "This NSPersistentStoreCoordinator has no persistent stores. It cannot perform a save operation." Error Occurs

Tags: ios, core-data, ios7, nsmanagedobjectcontext, core-data-migration

> "nspersistentstorecoordinator has no persistent stores. it cannot
>   perform a save operation background thread".

Can saving manageContext on background thread cause this issue ?

Sorry if this is already asked. I would like to know the probable reason for its occurrence ?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently you have created a memory-based persistent store coordinator, instead of one that use an SQLite database (the usual case) or XML for storage. Since there is no file holding the database, you can't save anything.

Check the code where the persistent store coordinator is created.

Answer (score 1):

If you used the default code from Apple verbatim then you are likely getting an error when creating the persistent store coordinator, but ignoring the error. Apple's boilerplate code checks for the error and has a comment in the if check that just says "/*Error for store creation should be handled in here*/". You should at least log a message in there to see if you're hitting that code path. If so, that's your issue. :)

NOTE: You can hit this problem when switching from new code (with a core data upgrade) to older code (e.g., in a branch) that doesn't have that upgrade. If you don't run clean in xcode, the compiled model file from the newer build can get put into the older build and cause you heartache.